# Issue with setting a custom property in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Let's say I got 2 ViewModels and 1 View

- ViewModel_A
- ViewModel_B
- View_A

in ViewModel_A I got a costum property class PersonClass
PersonClass has some fields

- Name
- Age
- Gender

In View_A i'm binding some textboxes to the PersonClass property which is binded two way with datacontext ViewModel_A
In ViewModel_B in want to update the PersonClass property **from code**.

Whats the best way to do this cause like I'm working at the moment I'm making a new instance of ViewModel_A in ViewModel_B and than set the property PersonClass.

```
ViewModel_A viewModel_A = new ViewModel_A();

viewModel_A.PersonClass.Name = someString;
viewModel_A.PersonClass.Age = someString;
```

...

Like I'm doing it now I got 2 different instances of ViewModel_A, so my property PersonClass will never notice any changes...
Whats the best solution to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your PersonClass must implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) and your View must get a viewmodel instance set as the [DataContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.datacontext.aspx). 
One nice way to handle with nested ViewModels, is to use [ContentControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.aspx)s
This is not necessary of course, but adds a nice way of customization, just switching the sub viewmodel allows changing parts of the UI.

```
class ViewModel_B
{
    public ViewModel_A MySubViewModel{get;set;}
}

<DataTemplate x:Key="vmaTemplate" DataType="{x:Type ViewModel_A}">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding PersonClass.Name}"/>
</DataTemplate>

<Grid>
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding MySubViewModel}" 
           ContentTemplate="{StaticTemplate vmaTemplate}"/>
</Grid>
```

This example assumes, that the `Grid` has as the `DataContext` an instance of `ViewModel_B`.